# Displaying the Long date format in formula bar

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In my excel sheet I have one-row having date format as 12-02-2016 after formatting to date it 14 February 2016 but in the formula bar, it showing as 12-02-2016. I tried to convert the cell values to text but it showing 42412 like this. How can I display the formatted data value(i.e  14 February 2016 ) in the formula bar also?

Comment: Try to convert date using 

    `=TEXT(A1,"d mmmm rrrr")`

and then copy and paste values to the next column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer for this is clearly explained by @Excel Tactics in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/650948/how-to-change-date-format-from-dd-mm-yyyy-to-dd-mm-yy-in-formula-bar-of-ms-excel).

**Quoted

There is no way to change the date format in the formula bar. Excel actually stores dates as serial number, so your example of 14 February 2016 is actually stored in Excel as 42412. You can use the format cell settings to change the in-cell output to whatever format you need, but there is no explicit "formula bar" format. It is just there as a way to show you the data contained in the cell.

The only way to change the view in the formula bar would be to convert the date to text using the TEXT() function, but then you would no longer be able to interact with the date as a number.

**Unquoted